# Boot from virtual disk

Tags: grub2, virtualbox

I run Ubuntu 17 native and I run Windows 10 in virtual box.
Can I boot somehow directly to virtual box image at boot?
Sometime I need to run the Windows 10 native but I don't want to use Windows 10 as main or with dual boot.

Comment: Seems pretty difficult, not to say impossible

Comment: Other way with Win 10 native and Ubuntu in vbox is possible and easy. But I woluld like to use Ubuntu Native. :)

Comment: @dsstorefile that would make a good Answer.

Comment: But I don't want to copy to phisical disk. I would like to boot to vdi from grub. In windows it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to boot windows 10 from a VHD on a windows partition (NTFS/fat32) if however you have no windows formatted partitions I feel it would be difficult if not impossible to accomplish. There are a couple of kernel mode ext2/3 drivers for at least some versions of Windows, however; I don't believe that compatibility extends to the bootmgr.

As an FYI a VHD is basically a DD image with one extra block at the end which is used by Windows and other programs that understand the format.

So assuming you already have a Windows bootmgr accessible partition that you can copy/convert a DD image into a VHD and transfer the file to, it is in theory possible.

This is all in theory and I have not attempted any of the aforementioned suggestions personally. Other than running Windows 7, 8, and 10 from VHD files on a NTFS formatted partition natively.

I have previously booted to DD type images from virtualization and from grub previously however those typically where ramdisks rather than file backed disk images. I have yet to successfully attempt a grub4dos grub2 file backed winvblock/firadisk boot of Windows from a VHD/DD file. There is documentation suggestion it is possible however.

Windows 7 (Ultimate/Enterprise) Windows 8 and Windows 10 all support native VHD boot